# Sorting System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch from a text file into a top 10

Tags: c#

The format is:

ElapsedTime(min, seconds, milliseconds) CurrentDate(day, month, year) DateTime(hours, minutes, seconds)

00:00:00 23/08/2020 12:24:37
00:00:00 23/08/2020 12:25:13
00:00:00 23/08/2020 12:25:18

I had a look at the Array.Sort methods, but not sure how to implement it. My idea is, sort them by ElapsedTime, less time goes first, and then display what date and what time they were recorded at. How can I sort this into an array?

FWIW, this is how I write to the text file, and also how I get and sort the time.

```
// Content of file
string content = timer.ts.ToString() + " " + System.DateTime.Now + "\n";

// Add text to file
File.AppendAllText(path, content);
```

`timer` is a reference to the Timer class, ts is stopwatch.Elapsed()

```
ts = stopwatch.Elapsed;

string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}.{2:00}",
    ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds / 10);
```

Comment: Work in reverse. Break your lines from text file at the first space so you have a TimeSpan portion and a DateTime portion. Then use [TimeSpan.Parse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.parse?view=netcore-3.1#System_TimeSpan_Parse_System_String_) and [DateTime.Parse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=netcore-3.1#System_DateTime_Parse_System_String_) to convert those strings into objects.  Create a custom class to hold both these values and put them in a List<>.  Sort your List<> and grab the top 10...

Answer (score 0):

Note : Below is the concept that you can take reference from. *This is not a running code*

```
class Program
{
    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch st = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        LogPerformance lf = new LogPerformance { TotalTicks = st.ElapsedTicks, LoggingText = "format of your lgging string" };
    
        List<LogPerformance> performanceList = new List<LogPerformance>() {lf,.... };
        LogPerformanceComparer comparer = new LogPerformanceComparer();
        performanceList.Sort(comparer);
        performanceList.ForEach(x => logger.Log(x.LoggingText));

    }

    public class LogPerformance
    {
        public long TotalTicks { get; set; }
        public string LoggingText { get; set; }
    }

    public class LogPerformanceComparer : IComparer<LogPerformance>
    {
        public int Compare([NotNull] LogPerformance x, [NotNull] LogPerformance y)
        {
            return x.TotalTicks.CompareTo(y.TotalTicks);
        }
    }
}
```